# Is there a simple short circuit protection available?

Tags: resistors, protection, short-circuit

One of my little copy/paste projects died again (a 12V 1 A circuit - [last time it died](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/442144/solenoid-switched-by-tip120-transistor-stopped-working-after-two-weeks?noredirect=1#comment1106564_442144)).
Now it was a short that caused it.

Is there a simple way of keeping my parts from burning?
By simple I mean something like a resistor that will burn before more expensive parts will, and that will cause the circuit to stop receiving power.

Also what are the problems that come with being simplistic?

Edit 1: So the circuit after all the answers looks like this:

[image]

Comment: \$30\:\text{V}\$ (**AC** and/or **DC**) seems excessive for a \$12\;\text{V}\$ relay. Is this the actual situation you need to cope with?

Comment: *Is there a simple way of keeping my parts from burning?* Sure! Operate them within their rated parameters! If what jonk says is true and you do operate a 12 V rated relay at 30 V then for sure you're **asking** for trouble.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie Since that time I have found a 15V AC/DC and after all the circuit it gives less.

Comment: Hmm, so the actual circuit you're using isn't shown in the linked question either. Then your question is similar to: *I build something, but I'm not showing you what it is, it has a problem, how do I solve it?* What makes you think that we do not need a **schematic** of what you made?

Comment: What about a simple fuse?

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie I don't see why the linked circuit isn't the actual circuit.

Comment: Because the linked circuit shows a 30V supply but your said you use 15V.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A simple resistor that burns before more expensive parts do is called a fuse. They are available for pennies at every major and minor electronics seller.

Comment: so where do I insert it, right at the + of the power supply?

Comment: Yes. So that it protects at much as possible of your circuit

Comment: do I need to calculate the needed fuse?

Comment: of course you do, you can't use the same fuse to protect a 10mA circuit as a 10 kA circuit.

Comment: Would a F2A250V be ok? This is what they gave me. This page recomends a 1A fuse. https://www.fusefactory.com.au/2019/08/23/how-to-calculate-the-correct-electrical-fuse-size-for-your-project/